# "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars" error occurs when taking cube root in python3

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
from numpy import cos
from tabulate import tabulate

def f(x):
    return (cos(x))**(1./3)

table=[i for i in range(50)]
table2=[]
for i in range(50):
    table2.append(f(i))
tables=[table, table2]
print (tabulate(tables))
```

When I run this code, it gives me a weird error. I looked up on the net some but they were all related to zero division. My problem occurs at numpy.cos when I used it before without "root" operation it worked fine. It also returns an error about tabulate as "'int' object is not iterable" which I really dont get it why?. Here is the error:

```
limit.py:5: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return cos(x)**(1/3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "limit.py", line 12, in <module>
    print (tabulate(table, table2))
  File "/home/yav/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tabulate.py", line 1247, in tabulate
    tabular_data, headers, showindex=showindex)
  File "/home/yav/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tabulate.py", line 933, in _normalize_tabular_data
    rows = list(map(list,rows))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I am just a beginner, so if you can explain more simpler, will be appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: You are misusing `tabulate()`: it expects a 2-dimensional data structure of some sort as its first parameter (with the second parameter being an optional list of column headers).  You're passing a 1-D list, so it's trying to interpret each of those ints as a row of the table.  I think you want `tabulate(zip(table, table2))`.  This is entirely unrelated to the RuntimeWarning, which is due to trying to take fractional powers of a negative number - this would fail even if you weren't using numpy's implementation of `cos()`.

Comment: So you mean python is struggling when taking powers of negative numbers? And corrected tabulate thank you.

Comment: *Mathematics itself* struggles to take fractional powers of negative numbers.  You have to go to complex numbers to make any sense of that - which you could do in this case by writing your function as `complex(cos(x)) ** (1./3)`.

Comment: Hmm... okay ı made such a thing;

 def f(x):
  if cos(x) < 0: 
   return -abs(cos(x))**(1/3)
  else:
   return cos(x)**(1/3)

now it doesnt give error, probably worked, but my tabulate behaves strange I am not sure how can I describe situation :/ briefly it doesnt make a table, instead aligns the values in a row but probably solved "cos" problem